# How to open bootstrap alert automatically after a given time frame?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I need your help:

I am trying to display a bootstrap alert at the bottom-right of the
 page automatically, 5 seconds after loading the site.

How can I achieve this. I tried my best, but I have not been able to make it work.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: "I tried my best" - what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the work for you with [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lubb4uwx/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="myAlert">
     Hello World!
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#myAlert
{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#myAlert').fadeIn('slow'); 
}, 5000);
```

Make sure you put the javascript at the bottom of your page just before the closing  tag (and wrap it with  tags

Comment: Dang.  This one up's me!  I'll concede this is better than mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I autoclose the alter after a given time and also include a clickable dismiss function?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`Timeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

```
setTimeout(function() {

  //Your code here

}, 5000); //5000 miliseconds
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  alert("Hello");
}, 5000); //In miliseconds
```

```html
In 5 seconds, an alert will appear...
```

Comment: instead of alert("Hello") in "setimeout" Max would insert his HTML that he wants to be displayed.  Max: upload your code please.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use setTimeout with an interval in ms.

Here is a working plunkr with the alert going to the bottom right.

https://plnkr.co/edit/S15Fp7DcPzB5EarnWVk6

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var time = 5000 //five seconds
    $('#alert').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#alert').show();
    }, time);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function. Here is an example

```
$('#my-alert').hide();
setTimeout(function(){ $('#my-alert').show() }, 5000);
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pnpu2bnm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to Chris Happy's answer:

Using a little bit of jQuery you can set the alert to visible inside the timeout function:

```
$("#alertToShow").show();
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#alertToShow").show();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
In 5 seconds, an alert will appear...

<div id = "alertToShow" class = "alert alert-danger" style = "display: none">
  This is an alert
</div>
```

Alternatively you could investigate the jQuery `.append()` function to add an alert to your page.